# Sumo select - how to make the listbox be loaded always open?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, sumoselect.js

[image: enter image deslist boxn here]

how to make the listbox be loaded always open? Like user click?

Comment: We need your code in order to help you. Treating Stackoverlfow like Google will not nessecarily lead to success. Please take the [Tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply add the class `open` to the sumo element like :

```
$('.SumoSelect').addClass('open');
```

Or base on your select selector like :

```
$('you_select_selector').parent().find('.optWrapper.multiple').addClass('open');
```

```js
$('#island').SumoSelect({
  placeholder: "TestPlaceholder"
});

$('.SumoSelect').addClass('open');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/HemantNegi/jquery.sumoselect/6c94c948/sumoselect.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/HemantNegi/jquery.sumoselect/master/jquery.sumoselect.js"></script>

<select id="island" multiple class="test">
  <option value="Big Island">Big Island</option>
  <option value="Oahu">Oahu</option>
  <option value="Kauai">Kauai</option>
  <option value="Maui">Maui</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, the first solution was perfect for my problem! tks from Brazil

Comment: I'm having problems, after I added the option:
jQuery ('. SumoSelect'). addClass ('open');

The asp: listbox is always open as expected, but when the user clicks on an item in the list, it does not select (does not select any item), other than the example you put above ... Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

I'm having problems, after I added the option: jQuery ('. SumoSelect'). addClass ('open'); The asp: listbox is always open as expected, but when the user clicks on an item in the list, it does not select (does not select any item), other than the example you put above

My code:

```
<script src="/js/Alex/jquery.sumoselect.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

```
      <script type="text/javascript">
             jQuery(document).ready(function () {
                jQuery(<%=lstBoxClientes.ClientID%>).SumoSelect({ search: true, searchText: 'Pesquise...' });                                                              jQuery('.SumoSelect').addClass('open');
                  });                                                 
      </script>        


  <asp:listbox runat="server" id="lstBoxClientes" selectionmode="single" DataSourceID="dsclientes" 
    DataTextField="cliente"  DataValueField="clienteid">
      </asp:listbox>
```